# How to calculate the age in ios?

Tags: ios, xcode, nsdate, nsdatecomponents

I want to calculate the age in the form of X years Y months Z days. Here is my code

```
 NSString *dateString = @"15-Sep-1997";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM-yyyy"];

NSDate *PrevDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];


NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSLog(@"Prev date = %@", PrevDate);
NSLog(@"today =%@", today);
NSInteger  years;
NSInteger months;
NSInteger days;

NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
unsigned unitFlags = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit;
NSDateComponents *dateComponentsNow = [calendar components:unitFlags fromDate:today];
NSDateComponents *dateComponentsBirth = [calendar components:unitFlags fromDate:PrevDate];

if (([dateComponentsNow month] < [dateComponentsBirth month]) ||
    (([dateComponentsNow month] == [dateComponentsBirth month]) && ([dateComponentsNow day] < [dateComponentsBirth day]))) {
    years = [dateComponentsNow year] - [dateComponentsBirth year] - 1;
} else {
    years = [dateComponentsNow year] - [dateComponentsBirth year];
    months = [dateComponentsNow month] - [dateComponentsBirth month];
    days = [dateComponentsNow day] - [dateComponentsBirth day];
}


NSLog(@"%d years %d months %d days", years, months, days);
```

Output comes : 17 years 2 months -9 days (It's taking 1 month more and subtract the days)
Correct Output : 17 years 1 month 22 days (upto Todays date)

Comment: just see that -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4463893/how-to-calculate-the-age-based-on-date

Comment: i already tried but not getting exact output

Comment: try this ->http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19202120/how-to-compute-age-from-nsdate

Comment: try this -->http://iosdevblog.com/2012/03/22/calculate-age-from-an-nsdate-in-objective-c/

Comment: i tried all that links getting same output

Comment: You tried all those links, and yet accepted an answer that used the same code as one of those links?  That does not make sense.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check below code.

```
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM-yyyy"];
NSDate *startD = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"15-Sep-1997"];
NSDate *endD = [NSDate date];

NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSUInteger unitFlags = NSCalendarUnitYear|NSCalendarUnitMonth|NSCalendarUnitDay|NSCalendarUnitHour|NSCalendarUnitMinute|NSCalendarUnitSecond;
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:unitFlags fromDate:startD toDate:endD options:0];

NSInteger year  = [components year];
NSInteger month  = [components month];
NSInteger day  = [components day];

NSLog(@"%ld:%ld:%ld", (long)year, (long)month,(long)day);
```

and output is

> 17:1:22

Maybe this will help you.

Comment: working great, thank u so much.